# Cannot ping DNS servers

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, ping, subnet

I'm in abit of a situation, here is what I'm up against:

So I have two server, on different subnets. 
Both servers can ping each other.

Server one 10.0.1.*
Server two 192.168.2.*

Server one can ping the DNS servers without any issues
Server two cannot ping DNS servers and only can ping Server One

Both server Firewalls have been disabled.

If any more information is needed let me know.

Million Thanks, 
S

Comment: What is the output of the failing ping command ?

Comment: Request timed out  with a 100% Loss

Comment: Check the gateway....

Comment: Why do you need to be able to ping your DNS servers?

Comment: To connect with AD I have issues on communicating with the AD server

Comment: Ping doesn't have anything to do with AD communication. So while you're spending your time troubleshooting ICMP, your AD problem is going unsolved. Why not troubleshoot the actual problem? What are the symptoms?

Comment: Please provide more information like what your DNS servers are, your routes, your IP addresses, etc. @joeqwerty makes a very good point too. If your problem is something with AD why not address that problem? Are you trying to join a computer to the domain and you are having errors communicating with the DC?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to resolve the ping issue, look at the routing between the two subnets.  If you want to resolve the AD issue, start troubleshooting that.  If you cannot even ping your AD controller, it will not be possible to join the domain.

Comment: Why would ICMP Echo Request / Echo Response being blocked have any bearing on Active Directory communications? Last I looked, AD didn't rely on ICMP for communication between hosts.

Comment: If your routing is so restrictive that you are unable to ping, more than likely the ports necessary for AD communication are restricted as well.  I realize that ICMP is not required for AD but it is a good troubleshooting tool.

Comment: Sure, there is a *possible correlation,* but if you state as a fact that "if you cannot even ping your AD controller, it will not be possible to join the domain", then it had better be a fact, which it is not. At the very least you should be qualifying that statement in your answer.

Comment: @NOW-Admin: [SF] is a platform for professional admins. Statements you make here need to be substantiated by facts (and not of the "alternative  facts" kind)  and just making random suggestions "to assist with troubleshooting" doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Thank you for your help in making my decision.  Looks like a great group here ready to help bash someone for thinking outside of the box or recommending non standard options.  See you in cyberspace.